# Why was 'extern' used in the noui.h file?

Tags: bitcoin-core, source-code

When I review the Bitcoin Core source code, I see the `noui.h` as a header file, but the method `noui_connect` has been declared with the keyword `extern`. I think there is no need to do this.

`extern void noui_connect();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`extern` before function prototypes does not have any effect. If it were a variable, it’d be needed to specify that the variable was declared somewhere else.

```
void noui_connect();

void noui_connect() {/*something*/}
```

^^^The compiler can easily find which is the prototype and which is the implementation of the same function. However,

```
// main.h
int a;
// main.c
#include "main.h"
int a = 5;
// util.c
#include "main.h"
```

^^^The compiler *might* create two symbols. One in `main.c`, one in `util.c`. To prevent creation of another variable, the `extern` keyword is used to leave the variable to the linker, the final step at compiling.

On the contrary, the function prototypes, not the implementations are put in header files, which are always left to the linker. Because that's the way function prototypes are designed, they don't need `extern`.

If you see `extern` before function prototypes, that's pure coding style, probably to be consistent with other `extern` variables.

Comment: Not just consistency, but also clarity. It explicitly signifies to the programmer "The function is not being defined here". Even though it is obvious to the compiler does not mean it must be obvious to developers.